# Can I skip jack studs and install a window directly to the studs if i use Simpson ties to support the header?

Tags: studs, window-frame

I am doing some upgrades on a redwood shingled one story cabin. I would like to install a 30 inch window in an existing wall between studs, 16" on center, cutting only the center stud. My question - do I have to use jack studs?

I believe I can install short studs to support the sill without damaging too much interior wall. There would not be enough room to install jack studs to support a header, so I would use Simpson ties to hold the header. The window (with nailing flanges) would then be nailed directly to the wall studs.

I really don't want to cut through two studs and have to open up more of the interior wall.  Is my plan reasonable?

Comment: What are "Simpson ties"? Please provide enough detail in your question for us to answer.

Comment: Read up a little on "advanced framing"    https://www.apawood.org/advanced-framing   There are other resources out there too.

Answer (score 4):

One thing to recognize about Simpson (or any other brand) of wood construction connectors is that they've been engineered for certain use cases. If one were builindg a chicken coop, play house, shelving, or other small project it may be completely reasonable to browse the connectors and choose any random bracket that mechanically fits. For a bearing wall in a a building for human habitation, though, one should use the brackets only for the kinds of connections the manufacturer has designed them.

I'm not suggesting your plan is impossible. It may be appropriate to use a joist or beam hanger, for instance, to support that header. But these usually are designed to mount to the face of a larger beam -- there may not exist a model designed to mount on the wide side of a 2x4 stud in a wall.

If you can settle for 27 inches rough opening rather than 30 then the minimally invasive scheme, along with traditional jack studs, could possibly be made to work.

Most builders would agree there's a significant amount of effort going to be required to build as you've described. They would likely not consider any other approach but to cut the wall open, frame in the usual way, and then repair the interior wall.

One problem you're likely to encounter is wiring in the wall. If there is wiring running through this area then there's no way to slide a new stud down into the wall cavity. It'll simply have to be opened so that the wiring can be dealt with properly.

Comment: Agreed, reading through the tables that accompany each connector, making sense of them and evaluating if it'll work in the non-standard application is likely more hassle than biting the bullet, cutting more drywall, and framing the window the right way, and far less risky.